# Does AdSense penalise sites who say “please disable ad-block”?

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

Does Google AdSense penalise websites that say "please disable ad blocking software… it helps pay our bills… blah blah…"?

Example of "please disable adblock":

[image: example]

It’s kind of asking to see (or click) my ads which is against Google AdSense policies.